# How to pass params to rails form correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, parameters

I'm new to learning rails.  I want to try and create a simple app where a user can write a post and then others can leave a comment on their post.

I have 3 models.  User, Post, and Comments. I'm having trouble bringing along the post_id and user_id in the parameters when I create a new comment.

This is my new method in my comments controller

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(user_id: params[:user_id], post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
```

In my server it looks like I'm passing the params key(not sure if thats the correct term) and I'm looking for the value.

```
Started GET "/comments/new?post_id=post_id&user_id=user_id" for ::1 at 2021-04-16 22:40:14 -0700
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"post_id", "user_id"=>"user_id"}
  Rendering comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 715)
  Rendered comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 814)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 10798)
```

The parameters I'm passing is "post_id" and it should be an integer corresponding to the correct post.

I'm not sure what to google to figure out how to get the params.  I thought maybe it was nested under the comments controller so I've tried

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new(user_id: params[:comments][:user_id], post_id: params[:comments][:post_id])
  end
```

That broke my code.  I'm at a loss.  I'm not sure what to even google to try and resolve this.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass through strong params:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :post_id)
end
```

And addition to that, I think you should use a post method for your http request.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't pass lot of parameters in 'GET' method. Use post method and for strong parameters as mentioned by @thibault, you need to pass the parameters in the following format

```
{"comments" => {"post_id"=>"post_id", "user_id"=>"user_id"} }
```

In the new action, you just need to render the form, and after entering the values in the form, use 'POST' method to create the comment. There are many form helpers in rails, you can have a look on them here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
I recommend you to use rails form helper 'form_with' - https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with

If you are new to the rails, use 'scaffold' and understand the things by observing the code and logs of each action.

```
   rails generate scaffold Comment
```